# setInterval sólo se ejecuta una vez

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, curl, setinterval

Buenos días compañeros.

Estoy tratando de hacer un pequeño script que monitoriza el estado de los trabajos que se inician en un servidor. La parte de la respuesta del servidor la tengo y funciona correctamente, pero es a la hora de revisar esa actividad cada X segundos cuando no consigo sacar adelante el script.

Por ahora sólo consigo que se ejecute la primera vez, cuando se pulsa un botón concreto. Al pulsarse ese botón, todo el código se ejecuta, llega a la sentencia del `setInterval`, que llama a una función `traerEstado` con dos parámetros, y se ejecuta la función pero sólo una vez... cuando creo que debería hacerlo cada X segundos indicados...

En este ajax a curl.php lo único que se hace es pasarle los parámetros necesarios a una petición curl que nos devuelve el idGenerado que luego necesitamos pasarle a la función traerEstado, para saber si ese ID de trabajo está ejecutándose todavía, si está en espera o si ha finalizado.

Adunto mi código actual:

```js
$('.btnProcess').click(function() {

  var opcion = $(this).data('opcion');
  var server = $(this).data('server');
  var folder = $(this).data('folder');
  var file = $(this).data('file');
  
  var param = "opcion=" + opcion + "&folder=" + folder + "&file=" + file + "&server=" + server;
  var resultado = $('.btnProcess[data-folder="' + folder + '"]').parent();
  var box = $('.idBox[data-folder="' + folder + '"]');

  if (opcion == 'tercios') var remove = 'recibos';
  else var remove = 'tercios'; 

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'exec/curl.php',
    data: {param: param, server:server, file:file},
    success: function(idGenerado) {
      resultado.html("<img src='img/loading.gif' height='20' class='imgLoading' style='vertical-align:middle;'> <span class='txt'>Generando: "+folder+".pdf</span>");
      box.val(idGenerado);
      console.log("EXITO: " + idGenerado);
    },
    error: function(idGenerado) {
      resultado.html("<img src='img/loading.gif' height='20' class='imgLoading' style='vertical-align:middle;'> <span class='txt'>Generando: "+folder+".pdf</span>");
      box.val(idGenerado);
      console.log("ERROR: " + idGenerado);
    }
  });

  var repeticiones = setInterval(traerEstado(idGenerado, server), 1000);

});



    function traerEstado(ID, srv) {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "exec/serverData.php",
        data: {idGenerado:ID, server:srv},
        success: function(respuesta) {
          console.log(respuesta);
        }
      })
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btnProcess">Click Me</button>
```

El fichero serverData.php, ahora mismo únicamente hace un `echo date("H:i:s")` que se recupera en la función y lo imprime por consola, por lo que yo entiendo debería mostrarme en consola, a cada segundo, la hora actual, pero como decía, únicamente la imprime una vez y se queda parado.

Comment: En el ejemplo verás que idGenerado es nulo

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Uno de los problemas lo tienes en la línea siguiente:

```
var repeticiones = setInterval(traerEstado(idGenerado, server), 1000);
```

Como ocurren varias cosas a la vez, te las voy a separar en dos líneas, el código es totalmente equivalente pero seguro que nada más verlo notarás el error:

```
var resultado = traerEstado(idGenerado, server); //no devuelve nada
//pero la función se ejecuta una vez
var repeticiones = setInterval(resultado, 1000); //resultado es undefined, no hay nada que hacer
```

Y la forma correcta de hacerlo:

```
var fn= function () {
    traerEstado(idGenerado, server);
};

var repeticiones = setInterval(fn, 1000);
```

Por otro lado, deberías esperar a la respuesta AJAX para lanzar esta función o idGenerado será `undefined`, algo como lo siguiente (hacen falta algunos cambios más, pero captarás la idea):

```
...
success: function(idGenerado) {
  resultado.html("<img src='img/loading.gif' height='20' class='imgLoading' style='vertical-align:middle;'> <span class='txt'>Generando: "+folder+".pdf</span>");
  box.val(idGenerado);
  console.log("EXITO: " + idGenerado);
  setInterval(fn,1000);
}
```

Comment: Claro !!, no veía el problema de asignar el seInterval a una variable que en sí misma, no es nada, cuando debería estar asignada a una función en realidad. Muchas gracias por la explicación!

Answer (score 0):

En el setInterval no es posible ejecutar cada "x" tiempo un función al que le pasamos unas variables. Esto hace que sólo se ejecute una vez.

Por lo que tienes dos opciones de hacerlo. Opción 1: ejecutar sin llamar a otra función.

```
var repeticiones = setInterval(function(){
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "exec/serverData.php",
    data: {idGenerado:ID, server:srv},
    success: function(respuesta) {
      console.log(respuesta);
    }
  });
}, 1000);
```

Opción 2: llamar a otra función sin pasarle variables.

```
var repeticiones = setInterval(traerEstado, 1000);

function traerEstado() {
  var ID= $("x").val();  //Recuperar valores
  var srv= $("x").val(); //Recuperar valores
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "exec/serverData.php",
    data: {idGenerado:ID, server:srv},
    success: function(respuesta) {
      console.log(respuesta);
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Gracias Iñigo. Con la solución que me aportaron hace un minuto y la explicación ya conseguí hacer funcionar el script como quería. Igualmente, tu explicación me ayuda bastante porque me va a permitir mejorar el código que ya tenía con otro mucho más sencillo e intuitivo

Comment: Si, parece que he tradado en contestar jajaja. Me alegro.