# Función setInterval en javascript solo se ejecuta una vez

Tags: javascript, setinterval

Estoy haciendo una funcionalidad que consiste en un cronometro que se actualiza cada segundo. El problema está en que solo se ejecuta la primera vez y luego no vuelve a ejecutarse. Por lo que el crónometro solo marca uno. He probado las siguientes respuestas pero el resultado es el mismo.

[setInterval sólo se ejecuta una vez](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/198339/setinterval-s%c3%b3lo-se-ejecuta-una-vez)

[Función JavaScript solo se ejecuta 1 vez](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/391841/funci%c3%b3n-javascript-solo-se-ejecuta-1-vez)

Este es el código que genera los problemas.

```
const actualizarCronometro = (seg, min) => {

    let segundero = 0, minutero = 0;
    
  if (seg < 10) {
        segundero = "0" + seg;
  } else {
        segundero = seg;
  }
    
    if (min < 10) {
        minutero = "0" + min;
    } else {
        minutero = min;
    }
    
    contadorSegundos.innerHTML = segundero;
    contadorMinutos.innerHTML = minutero;
};

const pasaSegundo = (seg, min) => {
    if (seg < 60) {
        seg++;
    } else {
        seg = 0;
        min++;
    }

    actualizarCronometro(seg, min);
};

cronometro = setInterval(pasaSegundo(seg, min), 1000);
```

Comment: Pues la primera pregunta que enlazas es exáctamente el mismo problema que expones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estas pasando contantemente por parámetros el mismo valor, por lo que tu cronometro no cambia entre llamadas. Después si quieres pasar una función con paréntesis al Interval podes encerrarla en una función flecha `() => { mifuncion(arg1,arg2) }`. Si lo que quiero es hacer un cronometro me convendría usar variables globales, entonces el interval solo modificaría esas variables globales y las mostraría, y no sería necesario pasar nada por parámetros:

```js
let segundos = 30, minutos = 1;

const actualizarCronometro = (seg, min) => {
  let segundero = 0, minutero = 0;
  if (seg < 10) segundero = "0" + seg;
  else segundero = seg;
  if (min < 10) minutero = "0" + min;
  else minutero = min;
  document.getElementById("segundos").textContent = segundero
  document.getElementById("minutos").textContent = minutero
};

const pasaSegundo = () => {
    if (segundos < 59) segundos++;
    else {
        segundos = 0;
        minutos++;
    }
    actualizarCronometro(minutos, segundos);
};

cronometro = setInterval(pasaSegundo, 1000);
```

```css
div{
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="segundos"></div> : <div id="minutos"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts2.js" defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Un pequeño detalle: la condicion de los segundos debe ser segundos < 59, en cualquier cronometro al pasar 59 segundos:

se incrementan los minutos.

los segundos pasan a 0.

Tu cronometro empieza los segundos en 0 y termina en 60, eso es incorrecto.

Answer (score 2):

Tu problema está en como pasas la función al `setInterval`, se debe pasar una función ya se con su nombre o declarándola dentro, pero cuando la pasas de esta manera `funcion()` es decir con los paréntesis, lo que realmente le estas pasando al setInterval es el retorno de dicha función, que en tu caso es un función sin return. Además, incluso si se pudiera, tendrías un segundo problema, que son los argumentos de la función que siempre serían los mismos y no te actualizaría nada, ya que a la segunda iteración volvería como los mismos "min" y "seg"

Puedes intentar poner min y seg como variables globales

```js
const actualizarCronometro = (seg, min) => {

    let segundero = 0, minutero = 0;
    
  if (seg < 10) {
        segundero = "0" + seg;
  } else {
        segundero = seg;
  }
    
    if (min < 10) {
        minutero = "0" + min;
    } else {
        minutero = min;
    }
    
    contadorSegundos.innerHTML = segundero;
    contadorMinutos.innerHTML = minutero;
};

var seg=0; var min=0;
const pasaSegundo = () => {
    if (seg < 60) {
        seg++;
    } else {
        seg = 0;
        min++;
    }

    actualizarCronometro(seg, min);
};

cronometro = setInterval(pasaSegundo, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="contadorSegundos"></div>
<div id="contadorMinutos"></div>
```